# Is password age cached locally, along with login?

Tags: windows-7, password-management

We have a number of users that work remotely (off-domain), and before I set the password age (and complexity) on our AD, I wondered if the password age is stored locally, along with the login data. The last thing I want is to bugger up anything for our remote users.

I can't find anything that suggests it does cache this locally (it really wouldn't make sense in my mind), but equally I can't find anything that suggests it doesn't.

Can anyone state the position categorically for me?

Cheers.